# C++ (cpp-netlib) http listener - how to remove headers

Tags: c++, http, httplistener, cpp-netlib

I created an HTTP listener that accepts POST requests for files. I followed this template almost exactly:
https://github.com/cpp-netlib/cpp-netlib/blob/main/libs/network/example/http/echo_async_server.cpp

I start my listener like so: `./build/http_listener 0.0.0.0 8000`

Then post file to the listener  using curl: `curl --form "fileupload=@file1.txt" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I noticed that the variable `body__`, which gets populated with the text of the file also gets populated with header data. I do not want this. How do I populate the variable `body__` without any header data?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body__` does not get populated with header data. What you see is multipart data that you submit with `--form <name=content>`. If you want submit raw file data use another curl command:

```
curl --data-binary "@file1.txt"  -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

`-X POST` can be omitted if is used with `--data-binary`, `--data`, `--form`.

Unfortunately curl does not send a file name. If a file name is required on a server side, specify the header `Content-Disposition`:

```
curl --data-binary "@file1.txt"  -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file1.txt" http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

---

**KB**

1. [--data-binary](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary)
2. [-F, --form](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F)

Comment: wow, you are a life-saver thank you so much! This worked for me. 

Do you know how the HTTP listener can retrieve the name of the original file if a header is not passed? I want the HTTP listener to store the name of the original file inside a variable. I want to use this variable for various purposes.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: thank you!! I appreciate your help. My program works perfectly now